# How would i go about filling a TDBEdit from MS Access table field in Delphi on button click

Tags: database, ms-access, delphi

I tried doing it two ways

First i tried just using the ADOTable1.Fieldbyname thing to fill a tedit from First_Class field in ms access db but that didnt display anything

```
procedure TForm5.btnzaprosClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  vremia: string;
  sysTime: tdatetime;
begin
  dbeTime.text:=vremia;
  dbeClass1.Text:=ADOTable1.FieldByName('First_Class').AsString;
end;
```

I also tried doing it through this complicated code

```
procedure TForm1.btnzaprosClick(Sender: TObject);
// Процедура определения количества билетов по выбранному рейсу
var
  vremia: string;
  sysTime: tdatetime;
begin
  if edDate.Text = datamodule2.ADOTable1DSDesigner.Text then
  begin
    { showmessage ('Нашел дату'); }
    datamodule2.ADOTable1.First;
    while datamodule2.ADOTable1.Eof <> true do
    begin
      if cmbNumber.Text = datamodule2.ADOTable1_.Text then
      begin
        { showmessage ('Нашел рейс'); }
      vremia:
        = datamodule2.ADOTable1_2.Text;
        delete(vremia, 1, 11);
      sysTime:
        = time;
        { showmessage (timetostr (sysTime)); }
        if sysTime < strtotime(vremia) then
        begin
          dbeTime.Text: = vremia;
          dbeClass1.Text: = datamodule2.ADOTable1_3.Text;
          dbeClass2.Text: = datamodule2.ADOTable1_4.Text;
          exit;
        end
        else
          showmessage('Данный рейс уже улетел в ' + vremia);
        dbeTime.Text: = '';
        dbeClass1.Text: = '';
        dbeClass2.Text: = '';
        exit;
      end
      else
        datamodule2.ADOTable1.Next;
    end;
  end
  else if edDate.Text = datamodule2.ADOTable2DSDesigner.Text then
  begin
    datamodule2.ADOTable2.First;
    while datamodule2.ADOTable2.Eof <> true do
    begin
      if cmbNumber.Text = datamodule2.ADOTable2_.Text then
      begin
      vremia:
        = datamodule2.ADOTable2_2.Text;
        delete(vremia, 1, 11);
        dbeTime.Text: = vremia;
        dbeClass1.Text: = datamodule2.ADOTable2_3.Text;
        dbeClass2.Text: = datamodule2.ADOTable2_4.Text;
        exit;
      end
      else
        datamodule2.ADOTable2.Next;
    end;
  end
  else if edDate.Text = datamodule2.ADOTable3DSDesigner.Text then
  begin
    datamodule2.ADOTable3.First;
    while datamodule2.ADOTable3.Eof <> true do
    begin
      if cmbNumber.Text = datamodule2.ADOTable3_.Text then
      begin
      vremia:
        = datamodule2.ADOTable3_2.Text;
        delete(vremia, 1, 11);
        dbeTime.Text: = vremia;
        dbeClass1.Text: = datamodule2.ADOTable3_3.Text;
        dbeClass2.Text: = datamodule2.ADOTable3_4.Text;
        exit;
      end
      else
        datamodule2.ADOTable3.Next;
    end;
  end
  else
  begin
    showmessage('Билетов на данный рейс нет');
    dbeTime.Text: = '';
    dbeClass1.Text: = '';
    dbeClass2.Text: = '';
  end;
end;
```

but that instantly spit loads of errors so i opted to not use it

So how exactly would i go about filling a tdbedit on clicking a button?

Comment: If you indent your code it becomes much easier to read.

Comment: http://etutorials.org/Programming/mastering+delphi+7/Part+III+Delphi+Database-Oriented+Architectures/

Comment: I think you may have missed the point of the Delphi components whose names are prefixed with `TDB`, like `TDBEdit`, `TDBGrid`, `TDBImage`, etc.  These are Delphi's so-called "data-aware"  controls.  The way you use them is to place a TDataSource on your form and set its DataSet property to the dataset which is the source of its data.  You then connect a TDBEdit, say, to the TDataSource and after that you can set its DataField to the field you want to access.  After that, the datacontrols will automatically receive data from the source dataset and send editing changes back to it.